# Karate - How count number of instances of element in JSON response with embedded elements

Tags: karate

I want to work out the total number of occurences of 'id' in the following JSON String.

Does Karate have a quick way of doing this?

If it was at the top level I could do response.result.length but they are are in the embedded elements of 'test'. I could do this in javascript but just wondering if Karate has a quicker method.

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "test": [
                {
                    "id": "x",
                    "price": "£5.00"
                },
                {
                    "id": "y",
                    "price": "£10.00"
                },
                {
                    "id": "z",
                    "price": "£10.00"
                },
                {
                    "id": "a",
                    "price": "£10.00"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "test": [
                {
                    "id": "b",
                    "price": "£5.00"
                },
                {
                    "id": "c",
                    "price": "£10.00"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
* def ids = $..id
* assert ids.length == 6
```

Do take some time to read about JsonPath in the docs.

Comment: Great thanks Peter...that's easier than the Javascript function I wrote:  * def countDeliverySlots =

"""
function (response) {

  let totalNumberOfSlots = 0;
  for (var i =0; i< response.result.length ;i++) {
    totalNumberOfSlots = totalNumberOfSlots+response.result[i].deliverySlots.length
  }
  return totalNumberOfSlots;

}
"""

Comment: @Matt happy to help. here's another interesting example: https://twitter.com/getkarate/status/1316747296382488586